# How can you make a bash script wait for sbatch job to complete before moving on to next process?

Tags: linux, bash, hpc, sbatch

I have a bash script that runs a model using sbatch. The commands/processes that follow the sbatch command depend upon outputs from the sbatch job. Is there a way in bash to have the script wait until the sbatch job is finished? I don't want to use the 'sleep' command with an arbitrary/appx. duration because the model can take different times to run.

The flow of the script is like:

```
export SOME_STUFF
#define paths
#run the model w/
sbatch ./job_card

#now wait until job finishes before running remaining commands which depend on sbatch outputs; e.g., mv, cp, ncks...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `wait` builtin?

Comment: @Jetchisel - that won't work; `sbatch` submits the job to a scheduler ... wait won't do you much good.  There's a need to query the `squeue` for the status in a loop.  Even though you wonder why not put all the things in the same job_card?

Comment: I hate `sbatch` now :-)